# max-width doesn't seem to work for absolutely positioned div using translate

Tags: html, css

I have a absolutely positioned div which is both horizontally and vertically aligned using `translate`. The problem with my code is that the `max-width` doesn't seem to work for this div. It is always less than what I set the value for `max-width`. Actually I want to make div responsive as well, so can't use `width` property otherwise horizontal scroll bar appears. I also tried `width:100%` along with `max-width:500px` but still no luck. How to force `max-width` to work so that div can become responsive?

**GOAL**

1. Div must remain both horizontally and vertically center aligned like the way it is now using `absolute` and `translate`
2. Div must stretch to the `max-width` value i.e. 500px when the browser window width is larger than this.
3. Div width must reduce to accommodate the browser width when the browser window is shrunk - it will make my div responsive.

Here's my code/demo:

```css
.center {
  border:1px solid red;
  max-width:500px;
  height:150px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">This div is horizontally & vertically center aligned.<br />The text is also horizontally center aligned.</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Everyone is suggesting me useless and irrelevant solution here. Please try to understand the problem with these below pictures:

**When only width:500px is used:**

[image]

**When only max-width:500px is used:**

[image]

**When both max-width:500px and width:100% are used:**

[image]

**Problem: div doesn't remain responsive even if I use both max-width:500px and width:100% (see the horizontal scroll bar):**

[image]

Comment: Use width and overflow:hidden

Comment: I think no one is able to fix it as long as we center align div using translate. I may have to switch to -ve margin with absolute position.

Comment: Please see my updates.

Answer (score 0):

max-width doesn't work on its own it requires a Width to be based on

```css
.center {
  border:1px solid red;
  max-width:500px;
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">This div is horizontally & vertically center aligned.<br />The text is also horizontally center aligned.</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but new contributors are always hasty in replying even before reading and understanding the question carefully. You just provided me my own workaround that I had already tried and explicitly mentioned in my question too. Resize the browser window, you will see the flaw!

Comment: I see what you mean - thanks for letting me know :). Is there any reason that you use this method for vertical & horizontal alignment or is it just an exercise? Why not flexbox or grid? Also look for min(), max(), and clamp() in CSS

Comment: I hope you have seen my updates. As I said in my comment above that I may have to switch to -ve margin and absolute if my current code can't be fixed. Actually I just want to fix the issue by keeping translate approach. That's all!

Answer (score 0):

The max-width prevent to go further than what you specified, but you can mix and match with & max-width for best result

for me the max width is ok if I stretch my browser width. Also it stops at width 502px. why 502 ? because 500px + 1px (2 times) = 502.

*Update*
the position is giving you a hard time because position=absolute is trying to taking the whole view port (screen) space. Which is bigger than the space for the div you are trying to display. I also sized down the width to 98% because the border aren't shown if you are using 100%. Remember border aren't taking in account of the full size. see above. Have a great day !

```css
.center {
  border:1px solid red;
  width:98%;
  max-width:500px;
  height:150px;
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">This div is horizontally & vertically center aligned.<br />The text is also horizontally center aligned.</div>
```

Comment: Absolutely nothing useful here.

Comment: thanks for your kind words.
the problem with the width is that in CSS the percentage are based on their parents width, length etc... So if you are trying to fill the whole space (same as its parent) I would suggest you to remove the position absolute. You can use fixed or leave it to default (inherit).

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you. Anyway, if I remove position absolute then my div won't remain center aligned which is main requirement of this design.

Comment: did you use the fixed position ? as in my snippet above ?
what happen to the div, it appears on the wrong place ?
maybe the problem is coming from the parent's div. or whatever container that wraps around your div. Do you want to share a little bit more of context ? thank you